# How to use Fog (rubygem) to only start/stop the aws ec2 instance, but not terminate?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, fog

I've ec2 instance at aws as EBS store thats why I can start/stop the server.

When I start it again, the data is persisted between restarts.

But how to use fog or other ruby gems to automate this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking but here is a shot to stop insance via `Fog`

```
conn = Fog::Compute::AWS.new(
{
 :aws_access_key_id=>"YOUR_KEY",
 :aws_secret_access_key=>"YOUR_SECRET"}
)

conn.start_instances("i-a3432cbb")

conn.stop_instances("i-a3432cbb")
```